# Responsive navigation menu toggle not working (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make my navigation menu responsive. I have made it so the navigation list items are hidden on mobile display and the menu

tag appears ready to be clicked to show the menu but can't seem to get my list items to show on click when on mobile display. Any help please?

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  var menuBox = document.getElementById('nav-menu');    
  if(menuBox.style.display == "block") { 
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
  }
  else { 
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
header {
    height: 128px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 4000;
    background: white;
}

header .nav-container {
    max-width: 100em;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 45;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

header .nav-container .logo {
    width: 14%;
    padding-top: 2.8rem;
}

header .nav-container p {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    header .nav-container p {
        display: block;
    }
}

header .nav-container nav {
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

header .nav-container nav ul {
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    header .nav-container nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
}

header .nav-container nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

header .nav-container nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 16px 10px;
    color: #00458b;
}

header .nav-container nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #00458b;
}

header .nav-container nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 500;
}

header .nav-container nav ul li ul li,
            header .nav-container nav ul li ul a {
    width: 100%;
}

header .nav-container nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

header .nav-container nav ul .menu-item-40 a {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="nav-container">      
        <p id="menu" onclick="toggleMenu()"> Menu</p>
        <nav class="nav" id="nav-menu" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-item">
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Services</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Windows</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Glass</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Doors</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Roofline</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Our Work</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in you css. Here

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    header .nav-container nav ul {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

you have given display: none to the 'ul' but you toggling the nav with your javascript.

Tip: Try using toggle in javascript

```
element.classList.toggle('className');
```

here you can have class with display: block and can toggle without checking if the element is already having display block or not.